# Echo missing after generating image

Tags: php

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
      . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
      . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
      . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);

    //echo '<a href=\'imagepng('.$im.')\'> Download </a>';
    echo "-----------------";

} else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

It shows the image but does not echo "==============".

Comment: Please add a meaningful question. What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: The code is basically for a generating an image from stream.It generates the image but when i try to print something after that it does't show anything on the browser....

Comment: Your content type is `image/png`. You're outputting an image. Where is there room for the textual output of dashes?

Comment: @user this is by design. You need to add the text content to the surrounding HTML document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

It prevents you from echoing something else than the picture on this page.
(Well it doens't, but your Browser thinks this still part of the picture)

If you want to echo picture and Text, you need a seperat file, e.g. like this

```
echo '<img source="./pic.php" alt="pic" height="20" width="20" />';
echo '______________';
```

wehere pic.php is the path to the file wich echos the picture.

Answer (score 5):

You told the browser to expect an image, therefore it's only expecting an image. *Everything* sent will be considered part of the data for that image. And no, it won't convert text you send into part of the image.

Comment: Yes. We usually use something called "HTML" for that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way of displaying both. As a disclaimer, I shall add not to use this in production, though. Not all browsers support this and it ain't purty:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html');

ob_start();
imagepng($im);
$data = base64_encode(ob_get_clean());

printf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s" />', $data);
print('---------');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating an image (hence the header) so if you echo something after that, you are basically echoing "---" after the bytes of the image. 
Your browser thinks your .php script is an image now and doesn't display the '---' as plain text and tries to add it to the image.